# remove "safely remove eject hardware and eject media' windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, hardware-detection

This icon in the system tray when a usb device is connected I never use and would like it removed / turned off.

[image]

Comment: Do you never disconnect your USB disks when your computer is turned on? If you don't use the feature safely eject before you unplug a USB disk while your computer is turned on, you risk dataloss.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible, ironically due to being detected as a removable device, it immediately will write data allowing the device to be removed without ejecting the device as you would in out of support versions of Windows. If you were to remove the flag, the device wouldn’t have this protection, and you would have no way to eject the device safely.

Comment: Downvoting because this is a really bad idea, as stated above, without any reasonable explantation (not that any can be found). You something never using something, even if it wasn't improper, also doesn't mean you should attempt to instantly get rid of it. Especially when it's one of X icons that could be displayed there and the menu is hidden by default. Just stick the important often used icons to taskbar.

Comment: @Destroy666 For some specific USB drives using this will only ever pop up the "device is still in use" error dialog. A lot of times, processes will leak handles. It is quite plausible that for a lot of users, this simply never works. So it is understandable that some users just want to remove it.

Comment: @roeland removing an icon doesn't solve problems with USB driver/system implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Although later versions of Windows 10 and 11 have set "Quick removal"
as the default data-handling policy of removable devices, using the
Safely remove icon is still recommended to avoid data loss.
Without using it, one has to keep an eye on the disk to check whether
it's still busy before unplugging, which is not the recommended way.

Nevertheless, many people have expressed the same wish on the internet,
so I will list some of the methods that were suggested.
Windows changes might invalidate some of the methods.

**Taskbar settings**

- While a USB device is connected, right-click the taskbar and select
  "Taskbar settings"
- Click "Select which icons appear on the taskbar"
- In the list, locate and disable an entry that may say something like
  "Safely Remove" or
  "Windows Explorer - Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media".

**Registry modification**

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray`
- Note down the value of the item `Services` for backup
- Modify the item so as to add the lowest bit.
  If the default value is `1c` hex or `28` decimal, set it to `29` decimal.

**Create Safely Remove desktop Shortcut**

For completeness, you may create your own Safely remove icon
on the desktop using the command:

```
RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
```